# APScheduler not executing as expected

Tags: python, apscheduler

I have a couple of custom modules which are being called from clock.py running `apscheduler`:

### Problem caused by APScheduler

apscheduler keeps inserting the same date over and over at scheduled intervals, when it should be checking the twitter feed first and then if different from google sheet insert else do nothing.

### Modules

1. **clock.py:**

   1. instantiates `BlockingScheduler()`
   2. schedules job
   3. `.start()` the job
2. **module tweet_bss.py:**

   1. checks a tweet feed:

      1. compares current feed value to a saved value in google sheets.
   2. `If` values are different:

      1. Adds new value to google sheet
      2. updates local status file
3. **module dev_smtplib.py:**

   1. checks status file

      1. if status `True`, sends an email update

> Currently the problem is with **clock.py and module a**

### clock.py

```py
sched = BlockingScheduler()
sched.add_job(tweet_bss.main, 'interval', seconds = 120)
sched.print_jobs()
sched.start()
```

### Module tweet_bss.main()

```py
def main():
    """
    This script will import the sheets module, open a connection to twitter
    pass account name and numb of tweets open a connection with sheets,
    if last row 'text' from 'sheets' != 'tweet text' and 'is not None'
    then it will enter the exchange into the spread sheet
    """
    last_row = sheets.row_count()
    last_entry = sheets.get_text(last_row)
    last_entry = str(last_entry)
    for tweet in tweets('tweet_account', 1):
        if last_entry != bss_extract(tweet.text) is not None:
            sheets.bss_insert([str(tweet.created_at), tweet.lang,
                               tweet.source_url, float(bss_extract(tweet.text))])
            pickler([str(tweet.created_at), float(bss_extract(tweet.text))])
            sc.bss_update(True)
            print(f'from tweet_bss.py for {TODAY} @ {TIME}')
            print(f'if {last_entry} != {bss_extract(tweet.text)} is not None')
            print(f'a. Twitter data inserted on {tweet.created_at} to sheets')
            print('b. pickler() function updated the pickle file with date and exchange rate to be used for email')
            print('c. The status.yaml was updated to True, letting the SMTP script know "update" can be emailed')
            print('~' * 45)
        else:
            print(f'from tweet_bss.py for {TODAY} @ {TIME}')
            print(f'No update needed:')
            print(f'\tSheets last entry {last_entry} == {bss_extract(tweet.text)} (current tweet exchange) and is not None')
            print('\t\t* The email pickle was not updated with exchange rate and date')
            print('\t\t* The status was not updated to True')
            print('~' * 45)
```

**What I expected to happen:**

- To have apscheduler call **tweet_bss.py** check the twitter feed **every time** the scheduled job runs, without cashing anything into memory and update the google sheet if `tweet_feed != google.sheets`

**What is happening:**

- `apscheduler` checks twitter feed Only once, and if `tweet_feed != google.sheets` updates the google.sheet as expected **BUT**

### The Problem

- `apscheduler` keeps inserting the same date over and over at the scheduled intervals, when it should be checking the twitter feed every time.

```
"""
print statements I wrote for particular conditions in Module A
"""

Pending jobs:
    main (trigger: interval[0:02:00], pending)

from tweet_bss.py for 2019-04-15 @ 15:12:09
if 5009.63 != 5015.26 is not None
Twitter data inserted on 2019-04-15 19:07:19 to sheets
pickler() function updated the pickle file with date and exchange rate to be used for email
the status.yaml was updated to True, letting the SMTP script know it can be email
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
from tweet_bss.py for 2019-04-15 @ 15:12:09
if 5009.63 != 5015.26 is not None
Twitter data inserted on 2019-04-15 19:07:19 to sheets
pickler() function updated the pickle file with date and exchange rate to be used for email
the status.yaml was updated to True, letting the SMTP script know it can be email
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
from tweet_bss.py for 2019-04-15 @ 15:12:09
if 5009.63 != 5015.26 is not None
Twitter data inserted on 2019-04-15 19:07:19 to sheets
pickler() function updated the pickle file with date and exchange rate to be used for email
the status.yaml was updated to True, letting the SMTP script know it can be email
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
from tweet_bss.py for 2019-04-15 @ 15:12:09
if 5009.63 != 5015.26 is not None
Twitter data inserted on 2019-04-15 19:07:19 to sheets
pickler() function updated the pickle file with date and exchange rate to be used for email
the status.yaml was updated to True, letting the SMTP script know it can be email
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

### How do I make apscheduler execute `tweet_bss.py` as intended?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you think the problem is with APScheduler? It doesn't contain any Google Sheets or Twitter code. Where do `TODAY` and `TIME` come from?

Comment: Hi Alex, I can't post the other scripts and modules because of the size. And I think you are right, late last night it occurred to me the problem is with the Scope within the main function posted above. I made the change, but haven't been able to test it, the power keeps going out. Again, this is part of a microservice and it's way to larger. Other problems may come up after this one is fixed.